# Uncaught TypeError breaks chat room loading

Tags: bug, chat, javascript

Every so often when I try and load a chat room, I get stuck on this screen:

[image: Loading Unix and Linux. Just a second...]

I finally checked the Javascript console this time; it had this error at the bottom:

```
master-chat.js:247: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'add'
```

Refreshing loaded the room correctly, and the error went away. I'm running Chromium 20.0.1132.27-r1 on Linux

Comment: I've had this happen before too, although I thought there was a chance maybe it was the chat userscript's fault.